# Suggesting email on email field

Tags: usability, forms, interaction-design, user-behavior, input-fields

Gmail makes up about a third of our customers. Today I heard the suggestion that we suggest autocomplete for common email domains such as `@gmail.com` for customers when typing in an email address in forms such as register, login, forgot password, etc.

Something much like what is done with addresses.

[image: Address Suggestions]

**Are there potential issues with suggesting email domains when entering an email?**

Comment: I don't thing that autocomplete makes sense here: The probability of the email address ending in `@gmail.com` stays the same, no matter what prefix has already typed (except that after `a.b@c` we know, it's no gmail). But you could offer some buttons for the most common suffixes or maybe a select for them (besides the common suffixes the list should include the empty suffix, so that any input is possible). By showing this list from the very beginning, you'd avoid the problem mentioned in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Email addresses are valuable to users, and you don't want to mistakenly suggest you already know their email.

#### Unlike addresses, which are public, a users email is private. It is a privilege for a user to give it to us.

By using autocomplete it's noble to help save users work, but it can mistakenly give the impression that it is a record inside your database (or a public record, which is even scarier).

If a user is logging into your site regularly, they'll probably see their own email address as they type from the browser storage in the input field anyway. It's a function of the browser. But that's a record of **information they themselves have previously entered**.

Registration with an autocomplete could be alarming, as you have no previous relationship or permissions from them.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem and similar suggestion to suggest the email addresses and when we dug deeper the we figured out that it can be achieved by importing the gmail contacts. So let me tell you in steps.

1. Screen is showing to send invite to people with a dialog box and two CTAs; one at the top saying **import gmail contacts** and second and the bottom saying **Send invite** somewhat like realtimeboard.com does(see image)[image: realtimeboard importing gmail contacts]
2. If the user clicks on **import gmail contacts** then he/she will be navigated to a different screen where google will authenticate this step and once the user approves, he/she will be renavigated to the default screen.
3. Now if you type anything then you will get suggestions on real time basis.
   [image: see the email added]

Images are taken from google
Answer could have been better but I'm using my phone this is why it is little messy. Sorry :P

Comment: Doesn't quite apply to our use case but interesting idea none the less!